# `GKGameCenterBadgingDisabled` plist key not working?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, game-center, gamekit

I'm trying to disable badges for my GameKit-enabled application. Based on [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW22), it looks like I should set the `GKGameCenterBadgingDisabled` key in my plist to `YES`. After setting this, incrementing my build number, and deleting and reinstalling the app, I'm still seeing badges.

Has anyone used this plist key before with success?

Comment: Tried to use it but it doesn't work for me either

Comment: same here... did you managed to make it work?